# What is the meaning of this tattoo?

Tags: symbols

I'm planning to get a small tattoo, and I found something that looks pretty cool, but can't get the meaning behind it(if there is any), does anyone know what this may mean?
[image]

Comment: I think that this is off-topic here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not at all a puzzle

Answer (score 4):

After an easy google search, it seems you're a fan of [Nick Jonas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Jonas)...

And the meaning is explained [here](http://www.cambio.com/2013/08/09/nick-jonas-shows-off-new-tattoo-what-does-it-mean-god/):

> **G** for God, a "greater than" symbol, and an upside down **V** and right-side up **V** to symbolize the "highs" and "lows."

By the way, I voted to close your question because it is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It means

> God is greater than hights or lows

G

> God

>

> Greater than symbol

^

> highs

v

> lows